# Is there a way to combine position_fill and position_dodge based on different columns in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dplyr)

df |> ggplot2::ggplot(aes(Sex, total_effect, fill = `Age Group`)) +
  ggplot2::geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "PRGn"))(20)) +
  theme(legend.position='none')
```

Produces this:

[image]

Now, I would like to dodge based on the sign of the `total_effect` column, which I've recorded in `sign`, but I can't seem to find a solution. I don't want to use facets ideally, is there a way to achieve this?

What I want:

[image]

Sample dataset:

```
df <- structure( list( `Age Group` = structure( c( 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L ), levels = c( "0", "01 - 04", "05 - 09", "10 - 14", "15 - 19", "20 - 24", "25 - 29", "30 - 34", "35 - 39", "40 - 44", "45 - 49", "50 - 54", "55 - 59", "60 - 64", "65 - 69", "70 - 74", "75 - 79", "80 - 84", "85 - 89", "90+" ), class = "factor" ), Sex = c( "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male" ), total_effect = c( 0.15, 0.31, 0.06, 0.06, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 0.07, 0.03, 0.02, -0.19,-0.03, 0.07, 0.05, 0.08, 0.27, 0.06, 0.27, 0.23, 0.28, 0.28, 0.37, 0.57, 0.45, 0.59, 0.37, 0.54, 0.61, 0.85, 0.37, 0.66, 0.55, 0.53, 0.29, 0.23, -0.08, 0.07, -0.08, -0.12 ), sign = c( "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "negative", "negative", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "negative", "positive", "negative", "negative" ) ), row.names = c(NA,-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame") )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible route would be to make the x position dependent on the two variables, though labels might need tidying:

```r
df |> 
  mutate(sign = factor(sign, levels = c("positive", "negative"))) |> 
  ggplot(aes(interaction(sign, Sex), total_effect, fill = `Age Group`)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "PRGn"))(20)) +
  theme(legend.position='none')
```

[image]

Another possibility would be to plot two `geom_col` calls:

```r
df |> 
  mutate(pos_fill = if_else(sign == "positive", `Age Group`, factor(NA_character_)),
         neg_fill = if_else(sign == "negative", `Age Group`, factor(NA_character_))) |> 
  ggplot(aes(Sex, total_effect,)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = pos_fill), just = 1, position = "fill", width = 0.4) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = neg_fill), just = 0, position = "fill", width = 0.4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "PRGn"))(20), na.value = NA) +
  theme(legend.position='none')
```

[image]

Less tidy code, but graph is closer to what you want already!